# Where to find webservice URL?

Tags: android, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

Where to find webservice URL in Cordova project which has integration of Microsoft Azure mobile services. I want to do an integration of Azure web service to an Android app.

Comment: Any update? If you feel my answer is useful /helpful.Please mark it as an answer so that other folks could benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where to find webservice url in cordova project which has integration of microsoft azure mobile services.

According to your description, I couldn't understand directly about your question.

No matter you used mobile app or web app, the webservice url is according to your server side codes.

The default url of the azure web/mobile app, you could find in the azure web protal's overview.

Like this:

```
http://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net
```

Then according to your server-side codes, it will go to different page to return some result to the client side.

If you use azure mobile app quick start easy table, then you could use azure client SDK to directly CRUD the data. It will also send request to the server backend to get the result.

Like this:

[image]

> Let me know if any one can help me in integration of azure web service to android app integration

Firstly, I should tell the difference between azure web app and azure mobile app.

Azure mobile app provide a lot of feature for us to easily created the your mobile application. Like esay table, Offline Sync, Push Notifications, Client SDKs and so on. If you use azure web app, you need implement these features by yourself.

So I suggest you could use azure mobile app as your mobile application backend.

Besides, the azure mobile app has quick start which we could easily create the  cordova project.

More details about how to create cordova project in mobile app, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started).

After you have created the app and download the project, it will auto create the easy table.

Then you could use azure mobile client SDK to get the database data.

In the downloaded cordova project's index.js file, you could find how it call the server-side to get the record.

[image]

Then it will use  client.getTable() method to get the table, and use this object to query the data.

Code like this:

```
 todoItemTable = client.getTable(tableName);
 todoItemTable
            .where({ complete: false })     // Set up the query
            .read()                         // Read the results
            .then(createTodoItemList, handleError);
```

More details about how to use azure client SDK to get data, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client).